# jquery find last element

Tags: jquery, html

What I want is, when i use the tab key on the last list select menu I want to get an alert. With the jquery i've got I will get an alert but on every select menu instead of only the last.

HTML markup

```
<div id="invoiceLinesForm" style="">
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="headerLine">
        <div class="qty">Aantal</div>
        <div class="description">Omschrijving</div>
        <div class="price">Bedrag EUR</div>
        <div class="total">Totaal</div>
        <div class="vat">BTW</div>
        <div class="actions"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>

    <li id="firstLine">
        <div class="qty"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[0][qty]" value="1" class="qty_input"></div>
        <div class="description"><textarea name="invoice_line[0][description]"></textarea></div>
        <div class="price"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[0][price]" value="0.00" style="text-align:right;"></div>
        <div class="total">0,00</div>
        <div class="vat">
            <select name="invoice_line[0][vat]">
                <option value="0.21">21%</option>
                <option value="0.06">6%</option>
                <option value="0.00">0%</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[0][total]" class="line_total" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[0][vat_amount]" class="line_vat_amount" value="0">
        <input type="radio" class="line_selector" style="display:none;">

        <div class="actions"><span class="delLine">Verwijder </span><span>Slepen</span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="extraLine">
        <div class="qty"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[1][qty]" value="1" class="qty_input"></div>
        <div class="description"><textarea name="invoice_line[1][description]"></textarea></div>
        <div class="price"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[1][price]" value="0.00" style="text-align:right;"></div>
        <div class="total">0,00</div>
        <div class="vat">
            <select name="invoice_line[1][vat]">
                <option value="0.21">21%</option>
                <option value="0.06">6%</option>
                <option value="0.00">0%</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[1][total]" class="line_total" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[1][vat_amount]" class="line_vat_amount" value="0">
        <input type="radio" class="line_selector" style="display:none;">

        <div class="actions"><span class="delLine">Verwijder </span><span>Slepen</span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="extraLine">
        <div class="qty"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[2][qty]" value="1" class="qty_input"></div>
        <div class="description"><textarea name="invoice_line[2][description]"></textarea></div>
        <div class="price"><input type="text" name="invoice_line[2][price]" value="0.00" style="text-align:right;"></div>
        <div class="total">0,00</div>
        <div class="vat">
            <select name="invoice_line[2][vat]">
                <option value="0.21">21%</option>
                <option value="0.06">6%</option>
                <option value="0.00">0%</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[2][total]" class="line_total" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_line[2][vat_amount]" class="line_vat_amount" value="0">
        <input type="radio" class="line_selector" style="display:none;">

        <div class="actions"><span class="delLine">Verwijder </span><span>Slepen</span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$('.vat select').live('keyup', function(e) 
{ 
    if (e.keyCode == 9) 
    {               
        $(this).blur(function(e)
        {
            if($(this).parent().parent().is('li:last'))
            {
                alert('last item');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        });                 
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if($(this).parents("li").is(':last-child'))
    {
        alert('last item');
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UtHKR/3/

Comment: `+1`, but I would use `closest()` here, as `parents()` would continue to go all the way up to the top of the DOM tree... and would potentially cause problems if there are nested lists.

Comment: @kmb385, I tried this but onfortunately I still get the alert on all select menus

Comment: @kmb385, what i didn't mentioned is that the li.extraLine is not in the originally html markup but I use jquery append() to add the li.extraLine. Maybe this had something to do with it?

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen give the updated fiddle a shot. I should have been using the last child selector.  If there is still an issue we will address the dynamically appended html.

Comment: @kmb385, live doesnt work from version 1.7 so that was the problem but now I'll get the message on all select menu even with your example. So the .append() is not effecting the last selector

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.vat select').live('keyup', function(e) 
{ 
    if (e.keyCode == 9) 
    {               
        $(this).blur(function(e)
        {
            if($(this).parent().parent().is($(':last'))
            {
                alert('last item');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        });                 
    } 

});
```

Comment: Answering questions like this is a *great opportunity* to let people know about other pitfalls in their code. Such as, why they should not use `.live()`, and how `closest()` is better than jumping manually up the DOM tree... You should look to improve upon the code as a whole, rather than just the specific question they're asking.

Comment: @Simon, I use .live() because the li.extraLine is added via jQuery .append() so I only get it working with .live(). Is there another solution then?

Comment: You can do `$('#sortable').on('keyup', '.vat select', function () { ... })`. Have a look in hte jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I'm using an older version of jQuery so I have to update first. Thnx for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I take ahrens hint serious and give you some input. My solution would be:

```
// Use on, so there is only one event listener
$('#sortable').on('keyup', '.vat select', function(event) {
    // Cache your event target
    var $select = $(this);

    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   

        $select.blur(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            var $clostestLi = $select.closest('li');

            if($clostestLi.is(':last-child') == true) {
                alert('last item');
            }
        });                 
}
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLGeb/